# Javascript parse input name with array

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I take a form input name that's part of an array and parse it into its components:

Examples:

```
<input name='student[0][name]'>
// Output ["student", 0, "name"]

<input name='student[]'>
// Output ["student", null]

<input name='student[0]'>
// Output ["student", 0]
```

I've tried using the regex `/(^.+?(?=\[))?\[(.*?)\]/gm` with matchAll but that gives me some weird groups.

My end goal is to create an object representing the form. For non array forms, its possible to use Object.fromEntries(formData) but this does parse inputs that are in an array. Other solutions I've found do not support names that are multi nested arrays.

Comment: This might be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but why not `[...s.matchAll(/[^\[\]]+/g)].map(([e]) => e)`?

Comment: That almost works, except for the test case where the input name has an empty []. Example "student[]". Is it possible to get ["student", null] or something similar?

Comment: `s.split(/[\[\]]+/g).map(e => e || null)`? I recommend providing more context, though, because there's probably a much less hacky way to achieve whatever you're hoping to do here.

Comment: Thanks, that still gives some weird cases such as student[0][name] returns ["student", "0", "name", null]. I'll post a new question with just my end goal of converting formData into an object where input names have arrays. You're right, I'm really asking about Y here and not X

Comment: You could also edit the question to ask what you really want to do, then show this `name=` with regex as your proposed but not yet working solution. You can remove the null by hand if the last two characters are `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it exists a faster way, but this works:

```
let str = "student[0][name]";
let splits = str.match(/\[?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]?/g);
// splits values still contain [ and ]
let filtered = [];
splits.forEach(split => 
    filtered.push(split.match(/\[?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]?/)[1]));
```